# Pivoting (without pivot) and rearranging the data to make a row repeat itself

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a data set from the World Bank that is arranged in the following way

[image: The rows axis containts the country names and each column has the coresponding year]

What i am try to do is to re-arrange the data into a three column format:
**Country** **Year** and the  **Data**.
Namely, each county is repeated for each year the data is present. It would look like this:

[image]

What would be the best method to make this rearrangement in **EXCEL**?
Pivot is not of much use here.

Pivot is not of much help here.
The most important thing is to make up the Countries and the Year columns.

Answer (score 0):

use power Query

select the range click data menu> click from table >>

will enter power query from there click in home menu >use first row as header >
go to transform menu > select first column dropdown unpivot columns >
select unpivot other columns >> go to home and click close and load [image]